# toolStripStatusLabel in multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am using `toolStripStatusLabel` in multithreading and although it is another thread which interact with the `toolStripStatusLabel` my invokeRequired method of the `statusStrip` always return false (I enforce the creation of the handle also). In this thread I can access the `toolStripStatusLabel` (from else clause), update it but my editing could not be shown in the main UI. Here is my code:

```
public void safeThreaded()
{                
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    StatusStrip ss = (StatusStrip)form.Controls["statusStrip1"];
    ToolStripStatusLabel label =   (ToolStripStatusLabel)ss.Items["toolStripStatusLabel1"];
    string text = "Written by the background thread.";
    if (!(ss.IsHandleCreated))
    {
        IntPtr handler = ss.Handle;
    }
    if (ss.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ss.Invoke(new updateTextCallback(updateText), new object[]{"Text generated on non-UI thread."});
    }
    else
    {
        // It's on the same thread, no need for Invoke
        label.Text = text + " (No Invoke)";
        MessageBox.Show(label.Text.ToString());
        ss.Refresh();
    }
}

private void updateText(string text)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    StatusStrip ss = (StatusStrip)form.Controls["statusStrip1"];
    ToolStripStatusLabel label = (ToolStripStatusLabel)ss.Items["toolStripStatusLabel1"];
    label.Text = text;
}

public delegate void updateTextCallback(string text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the owning thread is whatever thread you're calling `safeThreaded()` from - you're creating the Form with the `StatusStrip` and `ToolStripStatusLabel`, and then editing it all in the same thread.

If you were to create the Form in one thread, and then run your `safeThreaded()` function (*without* creating the `Form2` in it) in a separate thread, then you should see `InvokeRequired` be true.