# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'statusStrip' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I Have try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/142069/2126472

like `toolStripStatusLabel1.InvokeRequired`

but `toolStripStatusLabel1` has no `InvokeRequired`

and I has try this too.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15831292/2126472

and it error like invalid argument on

`SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                form.Invoke(d, new object[] { form, ctrl, text });`

when I use 
`ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, toolStripStatusLabel1, "This text was set safely.");`

but not error when I use `textBox`

My code have method that wait for `bool` from another method that use Thread to run in background.

```
Thread t = new Thread(TestRemoteDB);
t.Start();
// In TestRemoteDB() will call updateRemoteDBStatus()
```

like this

```
private void updateRemoteDBStatus(bool successful)
        {
            if (successful)
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel4.Text = "OK!";
                toolStripStatusLabel4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel4.Text = "Error!";
                toolStripStatusLabel4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you paste your complete code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toolStripStatusLabel in multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181277/toolstripstatuslabel-in-multithreading)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "This text was set safely."));
```

Comment: That won't work because a ToolStripStatusLabel doesn't have a BeginInvoke method. And even if it did it wouldn't make sense because ThreadHelperClass is already using Invoke to execute code on the UI thread. And it won't compile since the ToolStripStatusLabel is not a Control and thus can't be used with the ThreadHelperClass linked by the OP.

Comment: Lapsus, I meant "this" and wrote "toolStripStatusLabel". Tnx.

Comment: I think this is work and save me a lot line of code. Thank you very much @Marko Juvančič.